# create new column based on value column a mapping on column b get column c

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe like this:

| num | text | foreign |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 4 |
| 2 | bcd | 1 |
| 3 | efg | 3 |
| 4 | jkl | 2 |
| 4 | jkl | 1 |

i want to make new column based on 'foreign' column match with 'id' column and get the 'text' column.
so, im expecting:

| num | text | foreign | foreign_txt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 4 | jkl |
| 2 | bcd | 1 | abc |
| 3 | efg | 3 | bcd |
| 4 | jkl | 2 | efg |
| 4 | jkl | 1 | abc |

how the syntax to make 'foreign_txt'?
I cant drop any row.
i forget how to do it. can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `Series` creted by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df['foreign_txt'] = df['foreign'].map(df.set_index('id')['text'])
print (df)
   id text  foreign foreign_txt
0   1  abc        4         jkl
1   2  bcd        1         abc
2   3  efg        3         efg
3   4  jkl        2         bcd
```

Or:

```
df = (df.merge(df.drop('foreign', axis=1)
                .rename(columns={'id':'foreign', 'text':'foreign_txt'}), how='left'))
```

EDIT: If need first value of `text` by `id` add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), for avoid remove unique texts per `id` with aggregate `join`:

```
print (df)
   id text  foreign
0   1  abc        4
1   2  bcd        1
2   3  efg        3
3   4  jkl        2
4   4  jkl        1
5   3  aaa        8
    
#join unique duplicates
s = df.drop_duplicates(['id','text']).groupby('id')['text'].agg(','.join)
df['foreign_txt1'] = df['foreign'].map(s)

#get first duplicates
df['foreign_txt2'] = df['foreign'].map(df.drop_duplicates('id').set_index('id')['text'])

#get last duplicates
df['foreign_txt3'] = df['foreign'].map(df.drop_duplicates('id', keep='last').set_index('id')['text'])
```

---

```
print (df)

   id text  foreign foreign_txt1 foreign_txt2 foreign_txt3
0   1  abc        4          jkl          jkl          jkl
1   2  bcd        1          abc          abc          abc
2   3  efg        3      efg,aaa          efg          aaa
3   4  jkl        2          bcd          bcd          bcd
4   4  jkl        1          abc          abc          abc
5   3  aaa        8          NaN          NaN          NaN
```

Comment: oh sorry but the id column has several row with same value so it raises error. how i can deal with it?

Comment: @nabilahnran - What is ouput if multiple `id` ? Do you need first `id` like in edited answer?

Comment: i've edited my example. please take a look to the question

Comment: can i do it without drop any row?

Comment: @nabilahnran - Answer was edited in `EDIT1`

Answer (score 1):

you can apply `map` method..!

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'num': [1, 2, 3, 4,4],
        'text': ['abc', 'bcd', 'efg', 'jkl','jkl'],
        'foreign': [4, 1, 3, 2,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
foreign_dict = df.set_index('num')['text'].to_dict()
#print(foreign_dict)  #{1: 'abc', 2: 'bcd', 3: 'efg', 4: 'jkl'}
df['foreign_txt'] = df['foreign'].map(foreign_dict) 

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   num text  foreign foreign_txt
0    1  abc        4         jkl
1    2  bcd        1         abc
2    3  efg        3         efg
3    4  jkl        2         bcd
4    4  jkl        1         abc
```

Comment: oh sorry but the id column has several row with same value so it raises error. how i can deal with it?

Comment: so what value do you expect, if there are multiple ID's with same value but with with different data (text. foreign) ?

Comment: i've edited my example. please take a look to the question